# Привязка DataGrid к коллекции коллекций

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть датагрид к которому нужно биндить коллекцию из класса вью модели которая сама является составной из нескольких однотипных коллекций :

```
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Food>> FoodCollection{ get; set; }
```

Это коллекция `еда` которая содержит подколлекции `мясо`,`рыба` и т.д.

```
    public ObservableCollection<Milc> MilckCollection { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Meet> MeetCollection { get; set; }
```

классы продуктов отнаследованы от общего `Food`

```
    public class Food
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Prise { get; set; }
    }
    public class Meet: Food
    { }
    public class Milk: Food
    { }
```

Cтолбцы привязаны к `Date` и `Prise` а `ItemsSource` к `Food`

```
         <DataGrid x:Name="DGFoodtDetails" Margin="0,35" ItemsSource="{Binding Food}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="20">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" MinWidth="300" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Prise}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

В конструкторе класса вью модели заполняю коллекции мяса и молока примерно :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < set.Tables["Milc"].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                MilkCollection.Add(new Milc()
                {
                    Type = set.Tables["Milc"].Rows[i][2].ToString(),
                    Date = set.Tables["Milc"].Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                    CountPaper = set.Tables["Milc"].Rows[i][3].ToString()
                });
            }
```

и добавляю подколлекции в основную :

```
        Food = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Food>>();
        Food.Add(new ObservableCollection<Invest>(MilkCollection));
        Food.Add(new ObservableCollection<Invest>(MeetCollection));
```

В результате всего выше описанного : в главной коллекции находятся 2 подколекции, в каждой из которых по несколько обьектов,чьи свойства заполняют грид. НО на гриде отображается только ПО ОДНОМУ обьекту из каждой подколлекции. Если я поменяю `ItemsSource` датагрида с `Food` на `Milk` то все отобразиться корректно. Вопрос : как это исправить и правильно ли вообще использовать для таких целей столь громоздкую конструкцию. Спасибо всем кто дочитал )

Comment: Почему не привязаться просто к `ObservableCollection<Food>`, не понимаю?

Comment: Я так и сделал. Результат - в гриде показано только по 1 элементу из каждой подколлекции

Comment: Я так понимаю вы хотите продукты в строчках и их свойства в столбцах? Тогда надо сделать `ObservableCollection<Food> Food` и добавлять туда в цикле `foreach p in MilkCollection {Food.Add(p);}`

Comment: @RusArt понимаете правильно. Только возникнет ошибка приведения типов

Comment: ...покажите код после обновления